# Getting jquery slide value when user stop moving slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have slide and gettig values using jquery.

JS:

```
    var setRatingValue = function() {
        // Set text
        var ratingValue = $("#rating-slider").slider("value");
        $("#rating-value").text(ratingValue);
        // Change the background colour of the slider
        var hsl = "hsl("+ratingValue+", "+50+"%, "+50+"%)";
        $(".ui-slider-range").css("background", hsl);
        // Set text colour
        $("#rating-value").css("color", hsl);
   alert(ratingValue);

    };
```

html:

```
    <div class="magic-bar">
        <span id="rating-slider" class="ui-slider-range"></span>
        <span class="flip">
            <a href="#"> FLIP </a>
        </span>
    </div>
```

`ratingValue` gives rated values when user move slider. I need to post this final selected value to someother file.

But problem : When I move slider, it continuously keep alerting the value of slider. So I i post it, it will post each value on slider.

What I want: When user stops moving slider then only the value should be alerted. So that I can post single final value.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you not use the `change` event? http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

Answer (score 1):

populate an (hidden) input field with the ratingValue, When you post you'll send the current value

html:

```
<input id="myValue" value="">
```

javascript:

```
 $("#myValue").val(ratingValue)
```

Comment: Sorry, can you please tell me you are talking about which value?

Comment: sorry but still issue persist

Comment: replace alert(ratingValue); with $("#myValue").val(ratingValue), make sure the input field is within your form. And you could trigger the submit of your form on for example a mouseleave event (when the user scrolls away from the slider.

Comment: This change I already made but no change. and input field is nont withing form. I have not used form here

Comment: how are you posting then?

Comment: `                    $.ajax({
                            url: "invite_db.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {"category": category},
                            success: function(data) {
                                $(".articleContent").html(data);
                            
                                //setInterval("messageDisable()", 5000);
                            }
                        });` like this

Comment: then you have to add to the data array something like: "myValue": $('#myValue').val()

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery slider has a event for that, the [**change event**](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change).
It fires when the user stoped sliding (I supose a kind of `mouseup`).

So you could use:

```
change: function (event, data) {
    // do the ajax call
    // the value is data.value, explained in the jQuery docs
}
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tLazy/)

Comment: `change` event fires when user stop sliding(`mouseup`), but when user press & hold keyboard arrow buttons than `change` event fireup Continuously. So if anyone wants to get value when user stop sliding with mouse as well as keyboard arrow keys than we need to use `keyup` and `mouseup`. get one local variable & update it `onChange` event. than perform operation which you want duing KeyUp & MouseUp event.

Comment: during MouseUp Or KeyUp event check is mouse left button? OR is Arrow Keys? or not... 

`if ((event.type == "keyup" && ['ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown'].includes(event.code)) || (event.type == "mouseup" && event.button == 0)) { /* perform your operation */ }  `